# Why ant we have protected top level class in java?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, package, protected

If i have a top level class classA in packageA, and i want to make a classB extend classA, but i want to include classB in packageB, without any other class in packageB being able to have access to classA (so classA cannot be public), wouldnt this mean that classA must be accessible to its own package plus its children that are in other packages, hence shouldnt classA be protected?
obviously we can solve this by moving classB to packageA but what if we cannot do for some reason?

alright i guess i have to fill this in too, i tried making classA protected and i got an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In basis, what you asked for is **not possible**. The problem is a semantic/philosophy argument: What does `protected` really *mean*?

Sure, it's defined as: "Only accessible / visible by anything else in the same package, and any subclasses".

However, if I write:

```
class ClassB extends ClassA {}
```

where ClassB and ClassA are *not* in the same package, and ClassA has hypotetically `protected` access level, how does the chicken and egg situation work? In order to 'parse and understand' `extends ClassA`, we need to be in a valid context (in the same package, or be a subclass), but we aren't in that context quite yet.

We can update the lang spec to decree that for the purposes of understanding any `extends` or `implements` clauses, that we should act as if we are in the right context for the purposes of `protected`. But that is an additional complication.

Hence, instead, the spec erred on the side of caution and simply doesn't allow it.

So, to answer your *direct* question:

Q: Why can't we we have protected top level class in java?

A: **Because the spec says so**.

That's it. That's the answer.

I assume you find that answer not very satisfying. But it is the answer.

So let's instead answer your underlying question, which is *actually*:

Q: I have a class (`ClassA`) that I do not want any code outside of `ClassA`'s package to be able to access - I do not want any code to invoke static methods or read static fields (`ClassA.someStaticMethod()`), and I do not want any code to be able to create new instances (`new ClassA()`) either. However, I **do** want code outside of `ClassA`'s package to write `extends ClassA`.

But, unfortunately, the answer there is: That is a bizarre question, and I (and, evidently, the authors of the java language specification) cannot fathom any realistic scenarios where you'd want such an access level.

There is no access level modifier that means: "This method is not accessible to code outside of the class, **except** for source files who source file name starts with the letter 'Q', *those* can access it". For the same reason: That's so bizarre the authors didn't foresee any need for it, and therefore, the language doesn't support it.

I suggest you make it `public`, and document it accordingly. Alternatively, consider that the only useful things you can do with a class **are always focused on members of it**. There's nothing useful you can do with, literally:

```
class ExampleUselessClass {
 // the class is completely empty. There is nothing here.
}
```

Then who cares what the access level of that class is? It's not useful, in any way.

Thus, you can effectively get what you want *by making every **member** within `ClassA` protected instead*.

If you have:

```
public class ClassA {

  protected static final String SOME_CONSTANT = "Hello";
  protected int someField = 5;

  protected ClassA() {
    // our constructor
  }

  protected void foo() {
    // some method
  }
}
```

Then explain to me what code in other packages can do, that *you do not want it to do*? Think it through. Other code can't write `new ClassA()` (unless they `extends ClassA`), they can't write `ClassA.SOME_CONSTANT`, they can't write `someInstanceOfClassB.foo()` unless you override `foo()` in `ClassB`. What's left, other than academic pointless cases, such as, say:

```
Class<?> classRef = ClassA.class;
```

restricted access levels (`private`, package private, `protected`) **are API access tools**: They let you mark parts of your API as: "Hey, I do not feel like documenting precisely what these methods do, and I reserve the right to modify this stuff in backwards incompatible ways in point releases.".

It doesn't mean anything further. access levels aren't security tools. Code that wants to 'access private stuff' can do so trivially (using reflection, or just hacking the class file, that's trivial to do). That's not the point of `private` and friends. Whatever's left isn't API related and therefore isn't relevant. There's no purpose to denying other code from writing `ClassA.class` or otherwise referring to the existence of `ClassA` itself (not to anything it can do, i.e. any of its fields/methods/inner types).

Comment: okay thanks. thats pretty much what i meant. i thought there was some theoretical reason i was missing.

Answer (score -1):

you can not use protected

other way around it that you use sealed but both classes should be on same package

so this for class A

```
package a;

sealed class A permits B {
}
```

and this for class B

```
package a;

public non-sealed/final class B extends A{
}
```

or

```
public sealed class B extends A permits Z{
}
```

another option to define both class on single file like the following

```
package a;

class A {
}

class B extends A{

}
```

Comment: okay sorry but im a complete beginner to java i have no idea what sealed means. also i exclusively care about making classB a child of classA, while classB is still in packageB. The fact that i cannot name classes protected i know, the why i dont understand

Comment: do not be sorry i am beginner too

sealed mean that the sealed class on our case A will be extended by only the classes defined on the permit part

non-sealed mean any thing can extended it of course without forgetting to apply the public/package private modifier

i also modify my answer to add another option

why protected does not work case protected for classes apply only for inner class to be more generic for inner type that what the java creator choose to do

Comment: @zenmonkey for extra details about sealed https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/language/sealed-classes-and-interfaces.html#GUID-0C709461-CC33-419A-82BF-61461336E65F

Comment: okay cool but i dont really care what sealed means. i only gave the example of classB as a reason as to why we would need protected class. thats my question. understanding why protected class is not allowed. istill dont ge why.

Comment: The underlying question OP has is: "I want code outside of the package to be able to `extend` me, but if they aren't extending me, they can't do anything with me'. `sealed` __does not solve that problem in any way__, and therefore, this isn't an answer to the question in any way. I was toying with 'maybe OP wants sealed' too, but thinking it through, it just doesn't apply here.

Comment: this how the accessibility determined in java
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1

class a and b are top level class 
if you still want to know why no protected not allowed for top level class? 
short answer that what the java creator choose to do 
it same as why int is 4 byte bit size why not more or less?

Comment: @rzwitserloot totally agree but i do not have enough points to make comments so sorry

Comment: @rzwitserloot yes pretty much thats what  i mena. im trying to give an example where we would need a protected class. im trying to understand WHY protected classes are not allowed.